# How to add box price during checkout in woocommerce wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**How  to add box price during  checkout in woocommerce wordpress?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? You see, this is not a free code delivery site ...

Comment: Are you talking about shipping price ? or box will be applied to each product ? So additional price for each product. 
If you are going to say multiple product in separate boxes then packing into box itself is going to be a complex scenario. So what exaclty you are looking for ?
Have you tried anything ?